# Rendering smooth terrain with cubic bezier splines?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, bezier, spline

I'm trying to make a mountain landscape with bezier patches.

I have it such that it ensures C1-continuity, but it just does not work out.

[image: image describing the error]

What I have as input to the function, although it being generated just before the calculation, is a height map consisting of the heights of a n x n grid.
Then in my method I want to generate 16 control ponts for cubic bezier patches, for every grid.

I'm not able to do so however, as this results in strange results, my code:

```
    new PatchIterator(width).forEachRemaining(p -> {
        int w = p.first, d = p.second;
        Patch patch = new Patch();
        boolean lastWidthPatchExists = (w - 1 >= 0 && patches[w - 1][d] != null);
        boolean lastDepthPatchExists = (d - 1 >= 0 && patches[w][d - 1] != null);
        if (!lastWidthPatchExists && !lastDepthPatchExists) {
            patch.createFirstPatch(heightMapping[w][d]);
        }
        else if (lastWidthPatchExists && !lastDepthPatchExists) {
            patch.createWidthConstrainedPatch(heightMapping[w][d], patches[w - 1][d]);
        }
        else if (!lastWidthPatchExists && lastDepthPatchExists) {
            patch.createDepthConstrainedPatch(heightMapping[w][d], patches[w][d - 1]);
        }
        else {
            patch.createWithAndDepthConstrainedPatch(heightMapping[w][d], patches[w - 1][d], patches[w][d - 1]);
        }
        patch.submitAll(terrainData, w, d);
        patches[w][d] = patch;
    });

private class Patch {
    final float[][] patchData = new float[4][4];

    /**
     * Creates the first patch, which is not constrained to anything else.
     * 
     * @param height The desired height for the patch
     */
    void createFirstPatch(final float height) {
        loop((x, z) -> {
            patchData[x][z] = height;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a patch that is constrained by the previous patch in width, this guarantees C1-continuity of the Bezier Surface.
     * 
     * @param height The desired height for the patch
     * @param lastWidthPatch The last patch in the width direction
     */
    void createWidthConstrainedPatch(final float height, final Patch lastWidthPatch) {
        loop((x, z) -> {
            float y;
            if (x == 0) {
                //First point should be the same as the last point of the previous patch (C0-continuity)
                y = lastWidthPatch.patchData[3][z];
            }
            else if (x == 1) {
                //The three points (previous patch last two and current patch first two) should be on a line (C1-continuity)
                float previousDifference = lastWidthPatch.patchData[3][z] - lastWidthPatch.patchData[2][z];
                y = lastWidthPatch.patchData[3][z] + previousDifference;
            }
            else {
                //No constraints apply to these points
                y = height;
            }
            patchData[x][z] = y;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a patch that is constrained by the previous patch in depth, this guarantees C1-continuity of the Bezier Surface.
     * 
     * @param height The desired height for the patch
     * @param lastDepthPatch The last patch in the depth direction
     */
    void createDepthConstrainedPatch(final float height, final Patch lastDepthPatch) {
        float[] yValues = new float[4];
        Arrays.fill(yValues, 0f);
        loop((x, z) -> {
            float y;
            if (z == 0) {
                //First point should be the same as the last point of the previous patch (C0-continuity)
                y = lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][3];
            }
            else if (z == 1) {
                //The three points (previous patch last two and current patch first two) should be on a line (C1-continuity)
                float previousDifference = lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][3] - lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][2];
                y = lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][3] + previousDifference;
            }
            else {
                //No constraints apply to these points
                y = height;
            }
            patchData[x][z] = y;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a patch that is constrained by the previous patch in depth, this guarantees C1-continuity of the Bezier Surface.
     * 
     * @param height The desired height for the patch
     * @param lastWidthPatch The last patch in the width direction
     * @param lastDepthPatch The last patch in the depth direction
     */
    void createWithAndDepthConstrainedPatch(final float height, final Patch lastWidthPatch, final Patch lastDepthPatch) {
        loop((x, z) -> {
            float y;
            if (x == 0) {
                //First point should be the same as the last point of the previous width patch (C0-continuity)
                y = lastWidthPatch.patchData[3][z];
            }
            else if (z == 0) {
                //First point should be the same as the last point of the previous depth patch (C0-continuity)
                y = lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][3];
            }
            else if (x == 1) {
                //TODO I think that x, z == 1 should be a seperate case
                //The three points (previous width patch last two and current width patch first two) should be on a line (C1-continuity)
                float previousDifference = lastWidthPatch.patchData[3][z] - lastWidthPatch.patchData[2][z];
                y = lastWidthPatch.patchData[3][z] + previousDifference;
            }
            else if (z == 1) {
                //The three points (previous depth patch last two and current depth patch first two) should be on a line (C1-continuity)
                float previousDifference = lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][3] - lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][2];
                y = lastDepthPatch.patchData[x][3] + previousDifference;
            }
            else {
                //No constraints apply to these points
                y = height;
            }
            patchData[x][z] = y;
        });
    }

    void submitAll(final FloatBuffer data, final int width, final int depth) {
        loop((x, z) -> {
            int datax = x + (width * 3);
            int dataz = z + (depth * 3);
            data.put(datax).put(patchData[x][z]).put(dataz);
        });
    }

    void loop(final BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
                consumer.accept(x, z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the most relevant, can anyone help me out by giving tips?
Also, are there any algorithms specifically designed for dealing with this?

Comment: what do you mean with "does not work out"? your image looks like a smoothed surface, what part do you believe does not conform to what the bezier patch should be doing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It has all those 'ripples' in there, while I am aiming to have an as smooth as possible patch, thus an as smooth as possible terrain.

Comment: those ripples are a consequence of using bezier patches. If you want to smooth out the ripples, first smooth your coordinates (using nearest neighbour averaging, or wider convolution, etc) then build your patch with those.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm sorry if I haven't explained it well enough, as I've asked the question more times... But it is a heightmap that **is** actually smooth. For example in the top left, I go from height `0` to `0.1` possibly, and then next to it to `0.2`, etc.

Comment: from your image it looks like your control points are not at the right height. It looks like they've been generated at the same height as the coordinates, so your patch cross sections will look like ʅ (exxagerated). If you want a properly smooth surface, you're better off building a NURBS surface instead of a bezier surface.